# Can I trigger an ECS/Fargate task from a specific file upload in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I know that I can trigger a task when a file is uploaded (per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-ECS.html) however, how can I trigger a task when a *specific* file is uploaded?

Amazon seems not to have anticipated people having multiple jobs watching the same bucket for different files :(

Comment: What do you mean a specific file?

Comment: @MunavirChavody S3 will generate an event when any file lands in a bucket. I want to see an event only when foo/bar/myfile.* lands in the bucket

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this with CloudWatch Events from CloudTrail Data Events.

Head over to [CloudTrail](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/home?region=us-east-1#/configuration/new), and create a Trail for your account.

- For Apply trail to all regions, choose No.
- Under Management events, Read/Write Events, select none.
- Under Data events, select S3. Input your S3 bucket name and folder name (prefix) to log data events for, and select Write (don't set read).
- Under Storage location, create a new bucket or provide a bucket to be used to store the log files.
- Select Create

Next, create a CloudWatch Event rule that targets your ECS Task when the CloudTrail Data Event happens.

Head over to CloudWatch and [Create a new Event rule](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#rules:action=create).

- For the Event Source select Event Pattern
- Change the dropdown that says "Build event pattern to match events by service" to select "Custom Event Pattern"
- Enter the event pattern below:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "your-bucket-name" // this is the bucket where your events are happening
      ],
      "key": [
        "your-object-key" // this is the object key you want to trigger starting your ECS task, note that it's an array.
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

- Customize the `bucketName` and `key` above as appropriate for your use.
- For your target, select ECS Task, configure the task as appropriate.
- Select `Configure details`, give the rule a name and set the State to `Enabled`, and click `Create rule`.

Now that your rule is enabled, when you upload an object with the specified key to the specified bucket, CloudWatch Events will trigger the ECS Task you specified.

Comment: great answer but I wanted to know if it possible to trigger different ECS tasks for different file names? i.e.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a wildcard in your comment. To add to the event pattern from hephalump, you can indicate a prefix for the key as well, which will match to any key with that prefix, not just a specific key:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "your-bucket-name" // this is the bucket where your events are happening
      ],
      "key": [
        {"prefix": "path/to/key"}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

S3 does not generate events for a particular object, rather for events that occur within a bucket.  The image below is the S3 console for events that a *bucket* can send.

[image: S3 event configuration]

Note that there you could use the prefix and/or suffix to perhaps get close to what you want but individual objects cannot generate events.  A good option though would be a Lambda that can filter on the object name and, if it matches what you want, run the ECS task.